# Finding The Triangle Area

Tags: triangles, area

**I have already solved this problem but not completely. Answers are 24 or 36/7**

so the problem is next: We have a *Triangle KMN, KM = 6, MN - KN = 2*
**cos< KMN = 3 / 5**

*I have already used cosine theorem and get 24 but i don't get what am i missing and why does it have second answer Please someone give me hint*

**Chapter is ABOUT AREA... I think it somehow is connected to < KMN**

Comment: Your area 36/7 is smaller than your KM = 6! It seems this is not possible.

Comment: so that means  there is a mistake in keys? i thought so cause sides are constant and angel is also constant

Comment: i don't know man. In keys there are two answers. i guess you are right and only answer is 24

Answer (score 1):

The points $P = (x, y)$ such that  $PK-PM  = 3/5$ define a hyperbola so there are infinitely many of these points. However, an angle $\angle{KMN}$ given determines two points $N$ and $N'$ which in turn determine two triangles with different areas as shown in the attached figure.

[image]

Then there are in fact two answers to the problem.

Comment: Then can you tell me whats the way to get second triangle area? I just need hint man is it somehow connected to angel cosine?

Comment: The hyperbola has equation $(1):99x^2-y^2=8.91$. Besides  $\cos \alpha=\dfrac{3}{10}$ implies $\tan \alpha=\dfrac{\sqrt{91}}{3}$ then the line MP has equation $(2):y=\dfrac{\sqrt{91}}{3}(x+3)$. Solving in $y$ the system $(1),(2)$ you get two solutions $y_1$ and $y_2$ from which two areas of triangles of base $6$.

Comment: by $3 / 10$ do you mean $3 / 5$ ? and where is $P$ point? or what's $MP$. I am school boy so if you don't mind answer to those questions and beside what's (1). Is it something  constant formula or on this occasion and how will it help me? (I know i have silly questions but ....)

Comment: Yes because $2\cos \alpha= \dfrac 35$.On the other hand $P$ is a generic point of the line with pente $\tan \alpha$. The equation $(1)$ is the simplification (you do have to work something on it!) of PK-PM  = 3/5 (this equality defines infinitely many points $P=(x,y)$). If you really want to get the second answer you must necessarily consider the hyperbola.

Comment: looks like it's a big deal for me. Well i ll  do my best. Lastly are you sure that's the easiest way of solving it?

Comment: Yes Zura, apparently this problem exceeds your current possibilities. In truth I think you got the correct answer 24 by wrong means. Greetings. Good luck.

Comment: okey thank you man if i failed again i will write you  for solution. I hope i'll do it myself

Comment: Nice to help you, Zura, whenever you want. Good luck.

Comment: oh man i give up throw it to me

Comment: And yeh above your explanation you mentioned $2 cos a$ and there is jus $cos a$ beside i don t think that problem should be that kind of hard

Comment: Man dont leave me alone please answer xD